# Retrofit POST request converts into GET request when URL have "?" inside

Tags: android, post, opencart, retrofit

Retrofit converts POST in GET request when URL is like this

https://www.example.com/index.php?route=api/account/login

Answer (score 1):

```
Found the solution
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("index.php")
Call<String> login(@QueryMap(encoded=true) Map<String, String> options,@Field("email") String username,@Field("password") String password);

and calling will be like this
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("route","restapi/account/login");
Call<String> call = mAPIService.login(map, email, password);
```